# Opportunity Product Lookup Filter

Tags: managed-package, opportunity-lineitem, lookup-filter

I was trying to replicate an object fields in my developer org and i came up with an object(which is a part of managed package) and a field of it has Lookup Relationship with Opportunity Product.

[image]

How can I replicate this?

Comment: your question is not clear what you are trying to achieve